# How do I override the admin theme in my own theme?

Tags: 8, theming

I created my own Drupal 8 theme:

mytheme.info.yml:

```
name: My Theme
description: 'Drupal 8 Theme'
type: theme
base theme: bartik
core: '8.x'
```

mytheme.libraries.yml

```
global-styling:
  version: 1.x
  css:
    theme:
      css/layout.css: {}
      css/style.css: {}
      css/colors.css: {}
      css/print.css: { media: print }
```

I am using "Seven" as admin theme.

When I edit a page (/node/x/edit) Seven theme is used.

Now I have to add some CSS the the edit form. 
How can I do this?
style.css is only loaded on front end pages. Edit pages use seven theme and my theme CSS is ignored.

How can I add some CSS to admin pages or edit forms in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 24):

You can add admin CSS from a module hook.  Replace XXX with the module name.

1 Put your CSS in css/extra.admin.css

2 Declare a library by creating XXX.libraries.yml

```
extra.admin:
  css:
    theme:
      css/extra.admin.css: {}
```

3 Create a hook to load the library.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_page_attachments().
 */
function XXX_page_attachments(array &$attachments) {
  $theme = \Drupal::theme()->getActiveTheme()->getName();
  if ($theme == 'seven') {
    $attachments['#attached']['library'][] = 'XXX/extra.admin';
  }
}
```

Comment: Excellent. Straightforward and lightweight

Answer (score 18):

You cannot control one theme from within another theme. And even if some smart developer could find a hackish way to do it: please don't. Trust me, you don't want it. The concept of [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) is important in programming. Basically it means that the different moving parts (ie. your theme) of your system should take care of their own task, without interfering with the tasks of other parts (ie your admin theme).

To achieve your goal, the cleanest way is to create a new theme, [make it a subtheme of Seven](https://www.drupal.org/theme-guide/8/creating-a-sub-theme) (so it inherits everything you like about Seven) and add your custom CSS into the mix. Now you can select that theme as your admin theme instead of Seven.

Comment: Sorry, I can't believe that there is no way to solve this. I only have to add some CSS like img { max-width:100%; height: auto}. There must be a way.

Comment: No, there must not. Themes are not meant to mix. There can only be one active theme. If you need to do it, make a module, that can implement a form alter and add another library.

Comment: And what about Drupal 6 und Drupal 7? Also no solution?

Comment: >>Themes are not meant to mix. --> I do not want to mix themes, I only want to add one simple CSS!

Comment: @drupalfan, I don't understand why you conclude there is no way to solve this. There *are* ways (the Seven-subtheme method I described, and Berdir's method) and they are not hard to do. The kind of solution you suggested, is like asking a hairdresser to change the color of your shoes. Don't do it.

Comment: I you install a module that extends the edit form (e.g. image crop, etc) and the additional elements are not displayed in a way to fit to your page then you need a way to change this and make some additional CSS.    You can NOT leave this problem unsolved because your customer will not unterstand why you can not solve such a simple thing! You will not get your money until you solve this little problem.

Comment: @Berdir: How can I make a module in Drupal 8 to implement a form alter and add another library of CSS?

Comment: @marcvangend he means there is no solution to his question title `How do I override the admin theme in my own theme?`

Comment: `I do not want to mix themes, I only want to add one simple CSS!` that is considered mixing in Drupal. The only option you have is to either make a subtheme of Seven or "hack" the seven theme that is in `/core/themes/` but you will lose changes every time you upgrade drupal 8. So you will have to remember to upload the overridden .css file every time you upgrade D8. Therefore, you're better off making a sub theme of Seven and use that as you admin theme, because the subtheme will be located in the `/themes` folder and not inside `/core/themes`.

Comment: @NoSssweat Yes, you're right. Strictly speaking there is no solution to his question. That said, in years of webdevelopment I have learned to interpret questions as descriptions of the problem. We do offer a solution to the problem.

Comment: If it is possible to use a custom theme css for the content of a ckeditor window I don't understand why this shouldn't be possible for the whole admin theme.

Comment: I actually don't agree with this. If you are building your own stand-alone module, you might not want to even interfere with the admin theme in place, but still might need some CSS for your own purposes. You can simply attach your own module's libraries as needed without extending the whole theme in the traditional manner.

Comment: @Joum What you describe, is completely different. The OP was asking about letting one theme influence another theme. That is mixing responsibilities, especially since two themes can never be active on the same page. Shipping some CSS with a module is perfectly normal IMO - just keep it light weight, overridable, and strictly focused on whatever it is your module does.

Comment: On the subject of "mixing" themes (which is a bit of a vague term), I had a JS library (fancybox) in my public theme, I also wanted to use in parts of admin - probably not an uncommon request.  I created a subtheme of 'seven' and was able to simply refer to the `public/fancybox` in my admintheme.info.yml without needing to duplicate any of the assets or even require another .libraries.yml file.  Note you can't yet declare theme dependencies as you can for modules, though there's an issue - https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/474684 - in progress for that.

Comment: @Berdir you deserve a pat on the back. You saved my day. A module helped me to add js and CSS file to my admin theme without creating a subtheme for it.

Answer (score 5):

If you create a subtheme for Seven, and use that as your admin theme, you can add your own css overrides in the seven_subtheme.info.yml file, without messing with the core theme, or confusing theme responsibilities. The subtheme need only have the info.yml file and the css, and will inherit everything else.

- [Creating a subtheme](https://www.drupal.org/theme-guide/8/creating-a-sub-theme)
- [Theming fundamentals](https://www.lullabot.com/articles/drupal-8-theming-fundamentals-part-1) (eg adding css to your theme)

From the sounds of it though, you are mainly concerned with altering the css used by the wysiwyg editor (ckeditor), so you might instead want to look at adding `ckeditor_stylesheets` to your info.yml file. Note that, as explained in [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2674412), the *ckeditor* css can indeed be added from **your** theme, as the wysiwyg editor should use the non-admin theme css by default (remember to clear caches after adding this).

- [D8 how-to - custom ckeditor styles](http://www.drupalthemer.org/blog/drupal-8-how-to-ckeditor-custom-styles)

Comment: Proper answer. This is the way to do it.

Answer (score 5):

The module you're looking for is now called [Asset Injector](https://www.drupal.org/project/asset_injector). With it you'll be able to add CSS through the UI as @Whatwatt mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

Install [CSS Injector](https://www.drupal.org/project/css_injector) module (currently there is only a working development version for Drupal 8).

Then go to the administration page of CSS Injector (*/admin/config/development/css-injector*). Create a new CSS rule. For example, to change a field background color:

```
.node-form .field--name-title input {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Choose to apply this rule on *Seven* theme (or any admin theme in use).

Save and enjoy!

Comment: >>How can I add some CSS to admin pages or edit forms in Drupal 8?

Comment: I updated my answer, sorry for my mistake (I answered another topic!)

Answer (score 1):

To work with any admin theme I used AdamS answer and changed the hook to.

```
$config = \Drupal::config('system.theme');

$theme = \Drupal::theme()->getActiveTheme()->getName();

if ($theme == $config->get('admin')) {

  $attachments['#attached']['library'][] = 'XXXX/extra.admin';

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a block calling the css and insert it into the header of your admin pages?

@import url("/themes/XYZ/css/admin_overrides.css")

Answer (score 1):

You can add admin CSS from a module hook. Replace XXX with the module name.

1 Put your CSS in css/extra.admin.css

2 Declare a library by creating XXX.libraries.yml

```
extra.admin:
  css:
  theme:
  css/extra.admin.css: {}
```

3 Create a hook to load the library.

/**
    * Implements hook_page_attachments().
   */

```
function XXX_page_attachments(array &$attachments) {
  $config = \Drupal::config('system.theme');
  $theme = \Drupal::theme()->getActiveTheme()->getName();
    if ($theme == $config->get('admin')) {
       $attachments['#attached']['library'][] = 'XXXX/extra.admin';
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

i would create a separate child theme for both front and back office

Comment: But it is a bit of a pussle: http://www.skyriter.com/2018/04/07/step-by-step-guide-to-create-a-seven-sub-theme-for-drupal-8/

Comment: this tuto is 2years old. chid admin theme works smootlhly. Add a library to it for your css or js and here it goes

Answer (score 0):

There's the smartest way and the easiest way.
Easiest: At /admin/appearance, uncheck the box that says "Use the administration theme when editing or creating content" then apply custom CSS the same way you do for your main theme.

Alternatively, if you want your main theme to be used everywhere, set the Admin Theme dropdown to your main theme.

There are pros and cons to this, of course, but this is the easiest way to apply custom CSS to your admin theme--make it the same theme as your front end theme.

Smartest way: subtheme Seven per answers above.

If not committed to Seven, a combination easiest and smartest option: Install Adminimal theme. In the theme settings check the box for creation of a CSS overrides file.
Use that file to style to your heart's content.